# Dictionaries containing the biggest values

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have this scipy csr_matrix:

```
  (0, 12114) 0.272571581001
  (0, 12001) 0.0598986479579
  (0, 11998) 0.137415042369
  (0, 11132) 0.0681428952502
  (0, 10412) 0.0681428952502
  (1, 10096) 0.0990242494495
  (1, 10085) 0.216197045661
  (1, 9105) 0.1362857905
  (1, 8925) 0.042670696769
  (1, 8660) 0.0598986479579
  (2, 6577) 0.119797295916
  (2, 6491) 0.0985172979468
  (3, 6178) 0.1362857905
  (3, 5286) 0.119797295916
  (3, 5147) 0.270246307076
  (3, 4466) 0.0540492614153
  (4, 3810) 0.0540492614153
  (4, 3773) 0.0495121247248
```

and I would like to find a way to create (in this case 4) dictionaries where each dictionary contains the 2 biggest values for each row..

So for example, for row 0 my dictionary would be:

```
dict0 = {12114: '0.27257158100111998', 11998: '0.137415042369'}
```

and for row 1:

```
dict1 = {10085: '0.216197045661', 9105: '0.1362857905'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `csr_matrix` does not have a `sort()` method, it is convenient to transform the row you need to an array first:

```
a = m[i,:].toarray().flatten()
```

To get the positions of the sorted columns:

```
argsa = a.argsort()
```

The biggest values are at the last columns of `argsa`, so to get the columns of the two biggest values are:

```
argsa[-2:]
```

To get the pair `column, value`:

```
argsa[-2:], a[ argsa[-2:] ]
```

And this can be transformed in a dict:

```
dict( zip( argsa[-2:], a[ argsa[-2:] ] ) )
```

Your final function can be sth like:

```
def get_from_m(m, i, numc=2):
    a = m[i,:].toarray().flatten()
    argsa = a.argsort()
    return dict( zip( argsa[-numc:], a[ argsa[-numc:] ] ) )
```

Comment: From the looks of his array, its likely significantly faster to just loop through the indices instead of forming a dense array.

Comment: If you see the last edit, you are actually just transforming to an array the lines you want...